# SharePoint FBA mode - logout user on tab close

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, forms-authentication

We have a SharePoint 2013 site with forms based authentication. When user logs in and closes browser (whole browser) he is logged out. But when he closes tab in which he opened site, he is still logged in when he reopens tab and opens site again.

How we can logout user/kill session when tab in browser is closed?